# iText: Image in PdfpCell setAbsolutePosition does NOT work

Tags: image, pdf-generation, itext, pdfptable

I have a `PdfPTable` with 6 `PdfPCell`. I want to put an image in each cell at an absolute position. I just can get it to work, what am I doing wrong? As shown in the pic, the image always show on the to left (default) location.

```
laImage.scaleAbsolute(50, 50);  
laImage.setAbsolutePosition(0, 100);
laCell.addElement(laImage);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setAbsolutePosition()` method can be used to define the **absolute** position on a page (using the coordinates of the page) when adding an image to a document using `document.add()`. It is very surprising to discover that somebody would be using that method to define a **relative** position in a `PdfPCell`.

Depending on what you really want, you could either change the padding of the `PdfPCell` (to create a distance between one or more of the cell borders and its content) or you could define a border for the `Image` object. This will introduce relative offsets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just write the code based on my understand of HTML rendering. Will look into the diff between iText and HTML. THX!